How to ensure that NULLs from the database are exported to Excel spreadsheet as NULLs (or blanks cells) and not 0s
I am trying to export the results of a stored procedure to an Excel spreadsheet. However, although the database has some values of 0 (for temperature and hours of use) which are relevant values, it also has NULLs for columns where there is no data recorded.
When this is exported to an Excel spreadsheet, all the NULLs (and the legitimate 0s) from the database become 0. How do I ensure that that what is NULL in the database remains NULL in the spreadsheet? Obviously the legitimate 0s (for temperature etc), I would like to remain as 0s in the Excel spreadsheet as well.
So far I have the following C# code (what do I add to ensure a NULL is a NULL in the Excel export):
using System.Globalization;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Reflection;
using Api.Utilities.Services.Abstractions;
    

namespace Api.Utilities.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Provides functionality to export a collection of data into different formats.
/// </summary>
public class DataExportService : IDataExportService
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Exports a collection of data to an Excel file and returns the result as a file stream.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the data to be exported.</typeparam>
   /// <param name="data">The list of data items to be exported.</param>
   /// <param name="fileName">The name of the file to be exported, optional parameter. 
   </param>
   /// <returns>
   /// A <see cref="FileStreamResult"/> containing the Excel file.
   /// </returns>

   public FileStreamResult ExportToExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, string? fileName)
   {
        using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var currentRow = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            var customNameAttribute = properties[i].GetCustomAttribute<CustomNameAttribute>();
            var columnName = customNameAttribute != null ? customNameAttribute.Name : properties[i].Name;
         
            worksheet.Cell(1, i + 1).Value = columnName;
        }

        currentRow++;

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            foreach (var nestedRow in GetNestedRows(item))
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < nestedRow.Count; j++)
                {
                    var value = nestedRow[j];
                                    
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1).Value = value switch
                    {
                         null => string.Empty,
                         string str => str,
                         int intVal => intVal,
                         double dblVal => dblVal,
                         DateTime dtVal => dtVal,
                         bool boolVal => boolVal,
                         _ => value.ToString()
                    };
                }
            
                currentRow++;
            }
        }

        worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();

        MemoryStream stream = new();
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
               {
                   FileDownloadName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? "export.xlsx" : fileName
               };
    }

    /// <typeparam name="TData">The type of the data to be exported.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="data">The list of data items to be exported.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="MemoryStream"/> containing the CSV file.
    /// </returns>
    public MemoryStream ExportToCsv<TData>(IEnumerable<TData> data)
    {
        using var writer = new StringWriter();
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var properties = typeof(TData).GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            csv.WriteField(prop.Name);
        }

        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            foreach (var nestedRow in GetNestedRows(item))
            {
                foreach (var value in nestedRow)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(value ?? string.Empty);
                }

                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new(stream);

        streamWriter.Write(writer.ToString());
        streamWriter.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }

    private List<List<object?>> GetNestedRows<T>(T item)
    {
        var result = new List<List<object?>>();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var parentRow = new List<object?>();
        var nestedCollections = new List<(PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<object>)>();

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(item);
          
            if (value is IEnumerable<object> collection && !(value is string))
            {
                nestedCollections.Add((prop, collection));
            }
            else
            {
                parentRow.Add(value);
            }
        }

        if (nestedCollections.Count == 0)
        {
            result.Add(parentRow);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var (property, collection) in nestedCollections)
            {
                foreach (var nestedItem in collection)
                {
                    var newRow = new List<object?>(parentRow);
                    newRow.AddRange(property.PropertyType.GetProperties().Select(nestedProp => nestedProp.GetValue(nestedItem)));
                
                    result.Add(newRow);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}


null => string.Empty, why not null => null, In fact why not just simplify the whole thing to .Value = value is null or string or int or double or DateTime or bool ? value : value.ToString() or even just do .Value = value given that ClosedXML calls ToString anyway.

You need to actually debug your code and see what value is actually being used at each step where you think there should be a null. If you have a non-null value before the export then the entirety of your export code is irrelevant to the problem. It's up to you to do your due diligence first and work out where the problem is and exactly what problem you're trying to solve. It seems like you're just looking at the starting and ending states and ignoring everything in between.

Your code is so complex; closedxml can create a sheet from a datatable in one line: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet - see if it works better for you as a starting point, then format after

As an aside, if the data is tabular (which it is here), then it will be much more efficient to create an array in memory and use Range.Value=array to set the contents in one hit.
